# Is the connection pool shared between different managed servers in jBoss 6?

Tags: java, server, jboss, jboss6.x, application-server

The application is deployed on JBoss EAP 6.4, and running on different ports of the same instance:

[image]
My question is :

1. Would the connection pool of the data source be shared between the two managed servers?
2. If we have a master-slave configuration, and we configure a datasource for the master, will the JBoss instances running on other machines (as slaves), will share the connection pool of the master, or each instance will have its own connection pool?

Answer (score 2):

the datasource instance is per server (per jboss instance) and the connection pool is proper to the datasource.

So the answer is :

1. No
2. Each instance will have its own connection pool

Comment: *"the datasource instance is per jboss instance"*. Since both of my managed servers are running on the same jboss instance, why wouldn't these instances share the connection pool (Is having two servers on the same jboss instance, but different ports as shown in the image above, known by a name other than "managed servers"? Haven't been able to find much documentation about it)

Comment: This seems strange to me, I'd say you have a host and domain controller managing 2 server instances, both on the same host, but it's still 2 different jboss instances